# Linux delete file with size 0

Tags: linux, filesystems, delete-file, ls, rm

How do I delete a certain file in linux if its size is 0. I want to execute this in an crontab without any extra script.

```
l filename.file | grep 5th-tab | not eq 0 | rm
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 334, accepted):

This will delete all the files in a directory (and below) that are size zero.

```
find /tmp -size 0 -print -delete
```

If you just want a particular file;

```
if [ ! -s /tmp/foo ] ; then
  rm /tmp/foo
fi
```

Comment: shortcut: `[ -s /tmp/foo ] || rm /tmp/foo` (test if size is zero, else remove). Also note the `xargs` is unsafe if file/directory names contain spaces; `find ... -exec rm '{}' \;` is safe in that situation.

Comment: @Frank, you are incorrect about `xargs`.  The '-print0` and `xargs -0` corrects for the spaces.

Comment: @FrankH: Plus, even if using `find -exec`, always favour `+` over `;` in cases where you can (and this is one such case).

Comment: Would `rm --` (note the trailing `--` characters) be safer here than simply `rm` to prevent rogue filenames? http://serverfault.com/questions/337082/how-do-i-prevent-accidental-rm-rf

Comment: Is there also a command for running a dry run, to see which files would get removed?

Comment: @SimonBaars `find /tmp -size 0 -print0 |xargs -0 echo rm`

Comment: Why not simply `-delete`?

Comment: @Ruslan because `-delete` is new, and my version works with every version of `find` produced in the last 40 years.

Comment: Is `-print0` really 40 years old and ubiquitous?

Comment: @Rusian pretty sure it was in BSD 4.3, although apparently it didn't get into strict SysV Unices like early AIX.

Answer (score 274):

you would want to use [**find**](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html):

```
 find . -size 0 -delete
```

Comment: I would add "-type f", as also directory are marked to be of size zero. The "dot" is optional.

Comment: The "dot" is optional for Linux, but not optional for Mac OS

Comment: There is an `-empty` option :-)

Comment: @lilydjwg Exactly, if we're allowed to use non POSIX flags, `find . -empty -delete` is the coolest. :-)

Comment: You can add `-maxdepth 1` for the current folder.

Answer (score 151):

To search and delete empty files in the current directory and subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -empty -delete
```

`-type f` is necessary because also directories are marked to be of size zero.

---

The dot `.` (current directory) is the starting search directory. If you have GNU find (e.g. not Mac OS), you can omit it in this case:

```
find -type f -empty -delete
```

From [GNU `find` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Finding-Files):

> If no files to search are specified, the current directory (.) is used.

Comment: I would add -name '*.SomeFileExtension' for example: if you wanted to delete just text files then I would use: `find . -name '*.txt' -type f -empty -delete`

Comment: @jspek, well, that depends if you have that specific use... Usually when you are after empty files you are up to kill them all. :)

Comment: Had to grab a coffee after running this command on a directory with 2.2 million files. :P Had worked like a charm when I came back, 350.000 remained. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You can use the command `find` to do this. We can match files with `-type f`, and match empty files using `-size 0`. Then we can delete the matches with `-delete`.

```
find . -type f -size 0 -delete
```

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size 0 -delete

This finds the empthy files in the current directory without going into sub-directories.

Comment: To generalize this slightly, note that the value passed to [`-size`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Size) can have a suffix indicating the units. The default is _not_ bytes.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, the stat(1) command is useful when you don't need find(1):

```
(( $(stat -c %s "$filename") )) || rm "$filename"
```

The stat command here allows us just to get the file size, that's the `-c %s` (see the man pages for other formats).  I am running the stat program and capturing its output, that's the `$(  )`.  This output is seen numerically, that's the outer `((  ))`.  If zero is given for the size, that is FALSE, so the second part of the OR is executed.  Non-zero (non-empty file) will be TRUE, so the rm will not be executed.

Answer (score 5):

This works for plain BSD so it should be universally compatible with all flavors. Below.e.g in `pwd` ( `.` )

```
find . -size 0 |  xargs rm
```

Comment: Doesn't BSD support `-delete` option? https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)

Comment: @Antonio OpenBSD 6.0 at least doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-recursive delete (using du and awk):

```
rm `du * | awk '$1 == "0" {print $2}'`
```

Comment: -bash: /usr/bin/du: Argument list too long

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -empty -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: you can just use the -delete flag - saves an exec.