# remove all the files of zero size in specified directory

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu

Thanks,in advance
I want to remove all the zero size files in specified directory,can u tell me the command how to do it on Ubuntu OS.

Thanks'
Mukthyar

Comment: There's a duplicate question [How to remove zero byte files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859712/how-to-remove-zero-byte-files) with a more extensive answer.  I remain to be convinced that shell programming questions should be closed as off-topic; shell programming is programming and hence on-topic at SO.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157343/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475905 as well

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`find . -size 0c -delete` removes all such files in the current folder.

Comment: Thanks,in advance If i  want to remove all the zero size files,folder in specified directory,then how to do it...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you right, but the dot in the command is the current directory. If you want to delete the zero-byte files in folder `/foo/bar`, you issue `find /foo/bar -size 0c -delete`.

Comment: I like to use -type f to explicitly get just the files if the directory has deeper folders.

Answer (score 5):

```
cd DIRECTORY
find . -size 0
```

If you want to run a command on the files found (e.g. delete)

```
find . -size 0 -exec rm {} \;
```