# How to remove zero byte files

Tags: linux, unix

I have the following directory structure:-

```
foo/dir1/
foo/dir2/
foo/dir3/
foo/dir1/a.rb
foo/dir1/b.rb
foo/dir1/c.rb
foo/dir1/d.rb
foo/dir2/e.rb
foo/dir2/f.rb
foo/dir2/g.rb
foo/dir2/h.rb
```

How to remove zero byte files from a certain folder (some of the files under dir1, dir2 are zero bytes). How do I find and remove such files?

Comment: [`du`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_du.htm) may help point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the question [Remove all the files of zero size in specified directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907559/), but the other is closed 'off-topic' (which I don't agree with; shell programming is programming!), so I'm not sure it is a good idea to make this a duplicate of that question.

Comment: (Plus, I think the answer here is better than the answers in the possible duplicate — I think that's an objective assessment, but I am obviously not completely neutral on the subject.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have a version of `find` compliant enough with POSIX 2008 to support the `+` notation:

```
find foo -size 0 -exec rm -f {} +
```

If you don't, there are variants you can use:

```
find foo -size 0 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f   # But you probably have + anyway
find foo -size 0 -exec rm -f {} \;          # Slow but reliable
find foo -size 0 -print | xargs rm -f       # Fails with spaces etc in file names
```

And the accepted answer to the duplicate question suggests `-delete`, which is good when it is supported by the `find` you are using (because it avoids the overhead of executing the `rm` command by doing the `unlink()` call inside `find`):

```
find foo -size 0 -delete                    # Not POSIX standard
```

Comment: I think the `-0` stuff is older than the `+`, so there might be tool combinations who support `-0` but not `+`.

Comment: @glglgl: you're right — there might still be really old platforms with `-print0` and `-0` and not `+`, so I'll modify the answer to be less categorical in that comment.